# database connection on openshift using php

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I have used this code to connect to a database on localhost. What PHP code should I use to connect a PHP application to a database on openshift?

```
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "project";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle=mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found=mysql_select_db($database,$db_handle);
```

Comment: you run project localhost ??

Comment: you just edit this `$server = "localhost";`

Comment: On localhost it run correctly, i want to connect it to openshift phpmyadmin database

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables which are placeholders for values that are provided to a software program at runtime:

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); 
define('DB_USER',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT;
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Comment: I am new to openshift so don't know where to insert my database name, username, password. Can you please help me with it ?